# Is it OK to use a 17 V adapter instead of a 16.8 V adapter?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, adapter

I have an old model mixer which uses a 16.8 V, 500 mA adapter. The adapter broke and I cant find any adapter that provides the specific voltage and current. What I found is 17 V, 600 mA instead. My question is: can I use this adapter without breaking my mixer?

Comment: Should be fine. Just make sure the output matches the old one in terms of DC or AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m 99% sure you can use it. 16.8 V to 17 V is a 1.2% increase in supply voltage, and almost every product can operate perfectly within that range.

Answer (score 2):

Every electronic component, and every electronic circuit has a tolerance for its parameters. It is highly likely that a 17 V power supply delivers a voltage which is within the tolerance range of the required 16.8 V input of your circuit. If this were a life-critical situation, say for aircraft or medical usage, I would reject using "the wrong" adapter out of hand. But for everyday circuits, I would without any misgivings use the 17 V supply.

Answer (score -1):

Plug the power supply into AC (without connecting to your mixer) and measure the output voltage. If it is 17 V (with and without a load), you'll be fine. This means it is a regulated power supply with actual regulation.

Some older power supplies or low cost power supplies from things like low-voltage desk lamps, or other constant-load devices will have a voltage that changes significantly with the load that is connected to the supply (ie. an unregulated power supply).  Unregulated power supplies are designed for a specific load.  Regulated supplies deliver the same voltage to all loads.

If you plug your mixer into an unregulated power supply, the supply may have a significantly higher voltage than 17 V without a load. An unregulated supply is designed to deliver a specific voltage at a specific load. Google "unregulated power supply" for details.

Just measure the output to make sure, before you plug it into the mixer.

Comment: "Unregulated power supplies are" – It looks like the rest of the sentence is missing. (I didn't downvote this answer.)

Comment: Thanks - I don't know what happened there.